# How can these two equations be solved by elimination?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, nonlinear-system

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848213/how-does-wolframalpha-code-reduce-this-modulus-equation), the following two equations were solved using elimination. With a google crash course I sort of get how elimination works, but it seems like these are much too complex to add the left sides together in a way that cancels out x or y.

$$
\frac{3x(3x^2+9)}{2y}
-
\frac{(3x^2+9)}{8y^3}^3
-
y
=
6 \pmod {23}
$$

$$
\frac{(3x^2+9)^2}{(2y)^2}
-
2x
=
12 \pmod {23}
$$

Ultimately I'm trying to figure out any way (the easiest preferably) to reduce these such that `x=18, y=10` or `x=19, y = 3` in order to convert it to a function in a scripting language.

If elimination is the way to go, what were the steps involved in arriving at the following equation?
$$x^4-48 x^3-18 x^2+13968 x=-86481 \pmod {23}$$

Comment: Polynomial elimination based on resultants is a lot work to do manually. It's best left to a computer: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eliminate%5B%7B(2*x%2Bx)*(3*x%5E2%2B9)%2F(2*y)-(3*x%5E2%2B9)%5E3%2F(2*y)%5E3-y%3D%3D6,(3*x%5E2%2B9)%5E2%2F(2*y)%5E2-x-x%3D%3D12%7D,%7By%7D%5D)

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `R=QQ[x,y]` `f=3*x*(3*x^2+9)*(4*y^2)-(3*x^2+9)^3-(y+6)*8*y^3;g=(3*x^2+9)^2-(2*x+12)*(2*y)^2;` `factor(resultant(f,g,y))` yields
$(x^2+3)^6(x^4-48x^3-18x^2+13968x+86481)(46656)$. Change `QQ` to `ZZ/23` to do the calculation mod 23: $(x+5)(x+4)(x^2+3)^6(x^2-11x-8)(-11)$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland That is fantastic! Is there a way to see the steps involved in the arriving at the output? Ultimately I need to programmatically step through this process and it's difficult when the work isn't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to see how to get the equation by hand:

Introduce a third variable $$z = \frac{3x^2+9}{2y}$$ We have three equations

$$2yz - 3x^2 = 9\\3xz - z^3 - y = 6\\z^2 - 2x = 12$$

Multiplying the second equation by $2z$ and adding the first eliminates $y$:
$$6xz^2 - 2z^4 - 3x^2 = 12z + 9$$

Substituting for $z^2$ from the final equation gives $$6x(2x + 12)  - 2(2x +12)^2- 3x^2 = 12z + 9\\x^2 - 24x - 297 = 12z$$
Squaring both sides, then substituting for $z^2$ again
$$(x^2 - 24x - 297)^2 = 144(2x + 12)\\x^4 - 48x^3 - 18x^2  +13968x + 86481 = 0$$
Modulo $23$, this reduces to
$$x^4 - 2x^3 + 5x^2 + 7x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 23$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! You wouldn't happen to know how to get `x=18 or x=19` from your final answer, do you?

Comment: One could apply Ferari's equations, and reduce the answer modulo 23. However, since there are only 23 values that $x$ can be, it is easier just to calculate all 23 values and see which give a 0 result modulo 23. When you do the answer turns out to be 18 and 19.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the resultant yourself, you can use the Sylvester matrix (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix)).

In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/):

```
R=ZZ/23[x,y]
f=3*x*(3*x^2+9)*(4*y^2)-(3*x^2+9)^3-(y+6)*8*y^3;g=(3*x^2+9)^2-(2*x+12)*(2*y)^2;
sylvesterMatrix(f,g,y)
```

yields

$${\tiny \begin{pmatrix}{-8}&
  {-2}&
  -10 x^{3}-7 x&
  0&
  -4 x^{6}+10 x^{4}+7 x^{2}+7&
  0\\
  0&
  {-8}&
  {-2}&
  -10 x^{3}-7 x&
  0&
  -4 x^{6}+10 x^{4}+7 x^{2}+7\\
  -8 x-2&
  0&
  9 x^{4}+8 x^{2}-11&
  0&
  0&
  0\\
  0&
  -8 x-2&
  0&
  9 x^{4}+8 x^{2}-11&
  0&
  0\\
  0&
  0&
  -8 x-2&
  0&
  9 x^{4}+8 x^{2}-11&
  0\\
  0&
  0&
  0&
  -8 x-2&
  0&
  9 x^{4}+8 x^{2}-11\\
  \end{pmatrix} }$$

`determinant sylvesterMatrix(f,g,y)` gives the same output as `resultant(f,g,y)`.

As for factoring the output

$$-11 x^{16}-x^{15}-3 x^{13}-2 x^{12}-3 x^{11}+7 x^{10}-10 x^{9}+x^{8}+8 x^{7}-6 x^{4}+4 x^{3}+10 x^{2}+10 x+8$$

to $$(x+5) (x+4) ({x^{2}+3})^{6} (x^{2}-11 x-8) ({-11})$$

you probably don't need the whole functionality, just check on $x=-11,\ldots,11$ whether the value is divisible by $23$.